Will this proof work : $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{4^{k}} \,C_{2k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt\phi}$?
I know :$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\tan^{-1}(2\cos^{2}x)}{\cos^{2}x} \,dx=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt\phi}.$$
Now here is my proof to following series:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{4^{k}} \,C_{2k} =\frac{1}{\sqrt\phi}$$
Where $C_{2k}$ is the 2kth Catalan number
Let
\begin{align*}
S&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{4^{k}} \,C_{2k} \\
\implies \pi S&=
\pi\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{4^{k}} \,C_{2k} \\
&=\pi\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{4^{k}} \,\frac{(4k)!}{(2k+1)!(2k)!} \\
&=2\pi\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{2^{2k}(2k+1)} \,\frac{(4k)!(2k)(2k+1)}{(4k)(2k+1)!(2k)!} \\
&=2\pi\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{2^{2k}(2k+1)} \,\frac{(4k-1)!}{(2k-1)!(2k)!} \\
&=\pi\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}2^{2k}}{2k+1} \,\frac{2^{1-4k}\Gamma(4k)}{\Gamma(2k)\Gamma(2k+1)} \\
&=\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}2^{2k}}{2k+1} \,\frac{\Gamma(2k)\Gamma(2k+\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(2k)\Gamma(2k+1)} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}2^{2k}}{2k+1} \,\frac{\Gamma(\frac{4k+1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(2k+1)} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}2^{2k}}{2k+1} \,B(\frac{4k+1}{2},\frac{1}{2}) \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}2^{2k}}{2k+1} \,2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{4k}(x)\sin^{0}x \,dx \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}2^{2k+1}}{2k+1} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{4k}(x) \,dx \\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\cos^{2}x} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}2^{2k+1}\cos^{4k+2}x}{2k+1} \,dx \\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\tan^{-1}(2\cos^{2}x)}{\cos^{2}x} \,dx \\
&=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt\phi} \\
\implies S&=\frac{1}{\sqrt\phi}
\end{align*}
Is there already proof of this series or this post can work as the proof of above series?
And if this a new proof then Can I know where I can submit it on some kind of mathematical collection of proofs of series?

The generating function for $C_k$ is known,$$\sum_{k\ge0}C_kx^k=\frac2{1+\sqrt{1-4x}}$$and a similar method can be used to determine$$\sum_{k\ge0}C_{2k}x^k=\sqrt{\frac2{1+\sqrt{1-16x}}}$$The result follows by letting $x\to-\frac14$ from above.

A simpler proof is:
$$c(z):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n z^n=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}$$
hence
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty C_{2k}
\frac{(-1)^k}{4^k}=\operatorname{Re}(c(i/2))$$
$$=\operatorname{Im}(1-\sqrt{1-2i})$$
$$=\operatorname{Im}\left(1-\sqrt\phi+i\frac1{
\sqrt\phi}\right).$$
